# placing a figure side by side to a table that is atop a figure

Tags: subfloats, minipage

I am trying to insert a figure on the left and a table atop a figure on the right. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{A figure and a table atop a figure, side-by-side}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A figure left of a table+figure]{
        \rule{4.4cm}{6.6cm}
      }
      \subfloat[A table and figure right of a figure]{
        \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth} %
          \mbox{
        \subfloat{\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
      }}
    \mbox{
      \subfloat[A figure below the table]{
        \rule{4.4cm}{2.6cm}
      }
      }
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives me the following: [image]

and that is almost what I want, except that I would like the right figure to be below the table and both the right table and figure to be on the right of the left most figure. So,
like:

Figure a     Table a
Figure a     Table a
Figure a
Figure a     Figure b
Figure a     Figure b

How do I do this? What am I doing wrong above?

Comment: Nesting subfloats really messes up the captions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the baseline for a `\subfloat` (from `subfig`) is at caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \caption{A figure and a table atop a figure, side-by-side}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A figure left of a table+figure]{
        \rule{4.4cm}{6.6cm}
      }%\llap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}% to show baseline
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% align caption of first subfloat
    \centering
        \subfloat[A table above a figure]{\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}\par
      \subfloat[A figure below the table]{
        \rule{4.4cm}{2.6cm}
      }
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

A slightly more elegant solution.  The bottoms **and** tops align.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{A figure and a table atop a figure, side-by-side}
    \sbox0{\subfloat[A figure left of a table+figure]{
        \rule{4.4cm}{6.6cm}
      }}% measure height
    \sbox1{\subfloat[A table above a figure]{\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}}% measure width
    \sbox2{\subfloat[A figure below the table]{
        \rule{4.4cm}{2.6cm}
      }}% subcaptions are in the above order
    \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax% get total height
    \dimen1=\dimexpr \ht1+\dp1+\ht2+\dp2\relax
    \ifdim\dimen0>\dimen1\relax \dimen1=\dimen0 \fi
    \ifdim\wd1>\wd2\relax \dimen0=\wd1 \else \dimen0=\wd2 \fi

    \centering
    \usebox0\hfil
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimen1][t]{\dimen0}% align caption of first subfloat
    \centering
      \usebox1\par\vfill
      \usebox2
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```